# Password with 3 letters and 3 numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to calculate how many passwords can be when the first 3 elements of the passwords are letters, the 4th element is either 0, 1 or 2 and the 5th and 6th element is any number between 0 and 10 ? Numbers and letters can be repeated as long as the first number is either 0, 1 or 2.

I was thinking about 26*26*26*3*10*10

26*26*26 is the 3 letters, 3 is the 0,1,2 and the 10s are the 10 possible numbers.

Comment: Are they allowed to repeat (permutations)? Then the answer is just the product of the number of options for each element. Here is a PDF I found online which might be useful to you: https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~stephens/203/PDF/6-2.pdf

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answer rather than votes to close if you edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for the tip, I updated it with what I have tried already

Comment: I think you're right. I wonder why you were worried.

Comment: @EthanBolker I thought it was waay to big of a number that is why. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: It is indeed a big number. Now you can answer your own question here, or delete it.